# Move Mail storage from phone's internal memory to the SD Card

Tags: sd-card, internal-storage

I am not too concerned with the security aspect of putting my mail on the SD card, I am however very interested in moving the mail storage from the phone's internal memory to the SD card.

I have looked at the Gmail app and the stock Mail app and neither of them seem to be movable to the SD card so does anybody know if this can be done?

To be more specific, I really do not need to move the app itself, only the mail storage so if there is a way to move the storage location of mails from the internal memory to the SD card I would be very interested to know how that is done.

Comment: Suraj Bajaj: That is sadly what I also think but I would like to be sure.

David6: HTC Desire Z A7272
Android 2.3.3
HTC 2.1 (if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 3):

Only if you rooted, you can use data2sd ([original version at Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rappsd.v1&hl=ru); [later modification by enthusiasts at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1962507)), where /data/data linked to /sd-ext/data (or just sdcard mounted to /data). Then ALL application data will be stored on SD Card.

Answer (score 3):

[K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) supports to store mail on the SDCard. So if you're not bound to the GMail or the other pre-installed mail apps, this might be worth a try.

Details can be found e.g. at TechnosAmigos article [How to Save Email Data on your SD Card Rather than Internal Memory on Android Phones/Tablets](http://technosamigos.com/save-email-data-sd-card-rather-than-internal-memory-android-phones/). Basically, it requires the following steps:

- Go to *Settings → Account Settings*.
- Check for the *Storage* option
- Select the SDCard instead of internal storage

Done.

Comment: can I download @all@ of my emails to SD card? Optionally without images larger than X - I don't need photos, but would like to have all of my email available offline. Given the size of SD cards, why not?

Comment: @Mawg ask the dev. IMAP is server based. But a cache could be kept in sync, as clients on PC do. Technically.

Comment: Yup; thanks to your help on s/w rec, I am now Gmail free, using Thunderbird on PC, where I have everything offline, and K9 - as suggested, I will ask the dev

Comment: k9-mail does not any more support storage of mails on sd-cards. Unfortunately, otherwise I would have started to use it.

Comment: @Franz have you checked whether there is an open issue with the developers already? Maybe implementing SAF (Storage Access Framework, as needed for that with Android 11+ at least) is already on the todo list and just was not *yet* implemented with the rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

[K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9)'s option **Account Settings > Storage** will allow you to save messages to the **first** SD card. Most smartphones have no internal SD card, only the external. Thus my (Android 4.1.2) smartphone stores to `/sdcard/Android/data/com.fsck.k9/`. 
Most tablets have an internal and an external SD card and K-9 uses the internal. My tablet (also 4.1.2) stores to `/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.fsck.k9/`. AFAIK K-9 cannot store to the removable SD card sdcard1.